# Browserify r switch in Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, browserify

Im following an example that uses the following command:

```
browserify -r ./main.js:app > bundle.js
```

Im trying to automate this with Grunt and grunt-contrib-watch to automate the process but I'm getting errors.
Hers is the relevant part of my gruntfie.js

```
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
  grunt.config('browserify', {
    dist: {
      files: {
        'bundle.js': ['./main.js:movies']
    }
    }
  });
```

When trying the following in browser console:

```
app=require('app');
```

from the Grunt build I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

This example works perfectly if i manually enter the browserify command in the console.

What am I doing wrong, i guess i need to include the -r switch somehow?

Comment: `-r` is for `--require`, use [require](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-browserify#require) option. Or pass options directly to browserify using [browserifyOptions](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-browserify#browserifyoptions) option.